# Convert custom date format using a simple user-entered format

Tags: php

I need to import text files from various sources that will contain dates in various formats. Given how many messed up pieces of data I have encountered in the test files I have gathered so far, I have decided to force the user to enter their date format before importing the file, e.g. `MMDDYYYY` or `DD.MM.YYYY` etc.

I can't expect these users to understand enough to enter `Y-m-d` or `n/j/Y` formats which would be easy enough to parse, and I can't rely on "standards" like "if a dash is used, then month comes before day", etc., so automatic parsing is very much out of the question.

The other issue with the usual PHP date formatting is that I can't predict if any date format will have single or double digits, and I don't know how `createFromFormat` would parse this if I give them a single digit when it expects a double digit...

So my first thought is to start by separating pure numeric dates from others and force the user to enter a full 8 digit date along with the format code - otherwise it becomes messy. But that's as far as I've gotten so far...

I thought about parsing date and format string side by side, but that again would cause issues with one-digit numbers if I'm not careful.

I haven't found anything that'll help in my case, but maybe I'm taking this from the wrong angle - maybe there's a Javascript or jQuery date format selection tool out there that's compatible with the PHP date formats...

Any suggestions on the best approach for this?

Comment: Have you forced your users to input the format with only DD MM YYYY and combinations of delimiters? Or are they free to decide how the format is entered?

Comment: I can pick whatever I want - so far, there is no system to handle it yet. I just figured that MMDDYYYY is the most widely known. But I can't force the user to learn the difference between m and n and d and j for PHP format... On the other hand, I just found out that `createFromFormat` does in fact parse single digits correctly when it should expect double digits, so I might be able to create a conversion matrix myself now ...

Comment: why would they need to know the PHP formats? if you decide that they have to enter their format with MM DD YYYY, you can split the parts of the date's (from the data) with php, and put them back together the way you want. because you know which part of their data is the year, which is the month etc

Comment: Except I can't predict how many digits there will be. If the format is MM/DD and the date I get is 1/2, it's not as easy to parse. But I think I found the solution. Thanks for your comments, though!

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui has a good datepicker, i have used it in several apps to ensure the format of dates is always the same

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to pick a date, but a date format - the actual data comes from imported text files. What I'd need is for that date picker to allow me to pick a date format and then spit out the php date format string I need, e.g. "Y-m-d".

Comment: the jquery datepicker allows you to set the format you want used via a simple parameter

Comment: I think you don't understand my question... I don't need to enter a date at all. I need the user to tell my PHP processing code in what format the date in their file will be. If their file contains dates that look like 20131231, then I need to know either YYYYMMDD or Ymd in PHP in order to convert their date accordingly, so the user would have to let me know "YYYYMMDD" or "Ymd" - either of which is difficult for most of our users to understand. So again, datepicker won't help unless datepicker has a UI for choosing date formats.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the simplest solution. I was thinking way too complicated.

I'll restrict the date format input to 2 digits of M, 2 digits of D, and 4 digits of Y with any or no separator, then I can use this:

```
$str = '02-01-2013';

$format = "DD-MM-YYYY";
$matrix = array(
    "YYYY"=>"Y",
    "MM"=>"m",
    "DD"=>"d"
);
foreach ($matrix as $key=>$value)
{
    $format = str_replace($key, $value, $format);
}

$date = Datetime::createFromFormat($format, $str);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

This should work for me. Thanks for your suggestions! If someone has a better idea, I'm still open :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting the user enter a date format, let them choose a predefined one from a drop down menu. That way you will avoid a completely insane person entering "month day-YYYY" as a format or something else odd, or even just making a spelling mistake. Once you have a list of formats you can use php if statements to convert the date into whatever finished format you want.

```
$dateFormat = $_POST['dateFormat'];    
$date = $dateFromFile;
if ($dateFormat == "YYYYMMDD"){
   $cleanDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $date);
   echo $cleanDate->format('Y-m-d');
}
else if ($dateFormat == "YYYY/MM/DD"){
   $explodedDate = explode("/", $date);
   $year = $explodedDate[0];
   $month = $explodedDate[1];
   $day = $explodedDate[2];
   $cleanDate = "$year-$month-$day";
   echo $cleanDate;
} 
else if ($dateFormat == "Month DD, YYYY"){
    $explodedDate = explode(" ", $date);
    $month = $explodedDate[0]; 
            //change month from word into corresponding number
        if ($month == "January" || $month == "january" || $month == "Jan" || $month == "jan" || $month == "Jan." || $month == "jan."){
        $cleanMonth = "01";
        }
        else if ($month == "February" || $month == "february" || $month == "Feb" || $month == "feb" || $month == "Feb." || $month == "feb."){
        $cleanMonth = "02";
        }
        else if ($month == "March" || $month == "march" || $month == "Mar" || $month == "mar" || $month == "Mar." || $month == "mar."){
        $cleanMonth = "03";
        }
        else if ($month == "April" || $month == "april" || $month == "Apr" || $month == "apr" || $month == "Apr." || $month == "apr."){
        $cleanMonth = "04";
        }
        else if ($month == "May" || $month == "may" || $month == "May" || $month == "may" || $month == "May." || $month == "may."){
        $cleanMonth = "05";
        }
        else if ($month == "June" || $month == "june" || $month == "Jun" || $month == "jun" || $month == "Jun." || $month == "jun."){
        $cleanMonth = "06";
        }
        else if ($month == "July" || $month == "july" || $month == "Jul" || $month == "jul" || $month == "Jul." || $month == "jul."){
        $cleanMonth = "07";
        }
        else if ($month == "August" || $month == "august" || $month == "Aug" || $month == "aug" || $month == "Aug." || $month == "aug."){
        $cleanMonth = "08";
        }
        else if ($month == "September" || $month == "september" || $month == "Sep" || $month == "sep" || $month == "Sep." || $month == "sep."){
        $cleanMonth = "09";
        }
        else if ($month == "October" || $month == "october" || $month == "Oct" || $month == "oct" || $month == "Oct." || $month == "oct."){
        $cleanMonth = "10";
        }
        else if ($month == "November" || $month == "november" || $month == "Nov" || $month == "nov" || $month == "Nov." || $month == "nov."){
        $cleanMonth = "11";
        }
        else if ($month == "December" || $month == "december" || $month == "Dec" || $month == "dec" || $month == "Dec." || $month == "dec."){
        $cleanMonth = "12";
        }   
    $day = $explodedDate[1];
    $year = $explodedDate[2];
    $cleanDay = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$day);//remove extra characters from day
    $cleanDate = "$year-$cleanMonth-$cleanDay";
    echo $cleanDate;
}
```

You will have to figure out a way to convert each different date format you can think of. So it will take a bit of playing around. You can also give the user option to inform webmaster of an unlisted date format. Then get that option to send you an email so you can add it to the list.

Comment: I thought about that, but there's just too many possible combinations... I'll setup a few "ground rules" via JavaScript `onsubmit` to verify that we have pairs and fours, and that'll be it. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: no problem, hope you get it sorted, maybe someone can use my answer in the future!

Comment: That was my thought, too :-) Not everyone can have such inconsistent data as the stuff I'm facing ;-) What I have now should work - I just have to implement a few format checks in JS, then I'll be good.